# Difference between spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka and spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What is the difference between these maven dependencies in a Spring Boot project -

**spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka** and **spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka"  is a spring-boot-starter for easy version compatibility.

As you can see from the link, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/v3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka/pom.xml

"spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka" has only  "spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka" dependency info

So, if you use a spring boot, it is more convenient to use spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka

Comment: Is it possible to update the answer for:
1 spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka
2 spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive
3 spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams
4 spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka
please?